# VirtualBox - Cannot talk to guest via Host-only

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

I am running CentOS 6.2 with SSH enabled on Windows 7 and I cannot access CentOS via my host.

I have 2 adapters runnings, 1) Host-Only and 2) NAT.

My problem is very similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/369213/virtualbox-network-configuration) and I have configured both adapters, but I am still unable to access the CentOS machine.

We successfully pinged the machine from host.

Any ideas?

Comment: You said you can ping the guest by IP. How else do you want to communicate with the guest?

Comment: Did you try disabling SElinux or any firewall ?

Comment: @iglvzx I wish to communicate to the guest via SSH or through some means in which I can talk to a MySQL database, run backups etc.

Comment: @Ouki I've tried allowing the IP on my firewall but I have not yet tried disabling SElinux (if it is enabled). I will report back.

Comment: @Ouki, I figured it out. Port 80 was being blocked on the CentOS firewall. Thanks for your suggestions!